# MVC Model doesn't catch all model errors

Tags: model-view-controller, modelstate

This is part of a an MVC model class:

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(2, ErrorMessage = "Two characters.")]
    public string StateProvince { get; set; }
```

If I submit my form with a blank StateProvince, I will get an error message. If I submit it with one character in StateProvince, no problem. Here's how I get back error messages:

```
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            MyMessage ErrMsg = new MyMessage();
            ErrMsg.StatusCode = 101;
            ErrMsg.StatusMsg = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));
            return "[" + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ErrMsg) + "]";
        }
```

MyMessage is structured like so:

```
public class MyMessage
{
    public int StatusCode { get; set; }
    public string StatusMsg { get; set; }
}
```

Am I right to conclude that the StringLength decoration only serves to create client-side validation in the html input field?

Since I'm coding the HTML myself and not using Asp.Net to generate it, then should I just omit the StringLength decoration on the model field and instead write server-side validation code for that in the controller? (And that violates MVC, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Oops! Sorry! StringLength was working. It only prevents excess characters, not minimum number of characters. I know there's code for enforcing an exact length; I've seen it before and will look it up.